# Config file for Connection string in SSIS

Tags: deployment, ssis, configuration-files

I am new to SSIS, I have created variables for connection string (Both source and destination). While generating the Config file, which property I need to select. Could you please help me with this?

Comment: Config file is kind of the old way to do this but still works. I think you are trying to handle promotion of packages therefore each environment has it's own db server. The new way is to use package parameters and programming those in the call of the package from the job.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to create variables for a connection string.

There are a few things you will need to provide to us to give you an exact answer.

1. The type of database you are connecting to.
2. What type of authentication you use to connect to it.

If you take the below image when setting up a connection manager for an OLE DB you simply need to provide the server name. Then which type of authentication it is.

If the connection is successful you should be able to select a database you wish to connect to. You can also test the connect to make sure the connection is working successfully.

[image]

Let me know if you have any other issues.

Thanks

Gav

Comment: But it _is_ a best practice to declare variables for connection strings so that one can move a package seamlessly between environments; dev to uat to prod. Which seems to be exactly what Gnana is interested in doing.